# htaccess - 301 redirect url to another url adding more to domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would have an example of what I have done to attempt this already but with all my searching in Google I can't even find an example to start with. I need to 301 redirect the following url

from

```
http://www.example.com/words-that-end-with/letter/acy
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/acy
```

I would some assistance with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!word-lists/).+)$ /word-lists/$1 [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```